# Running out of memory on contact creation

Tags: contacts, webserver

On a site with ~68k contacts, we find that occasionally we get a memory error on a simple contact creation (although we haven't noticed problems elsewhere). We have a fairly large PHP memory allotment to start with, and although I realize I could increase that further I am a little hesitant to go too much further there. I'm assuming the process that runs the dedupe check could be responsible for this.

Can anyone confirm that the duplicate check is most likely the culprit here? If so, is there a setting to disable that?

Comment: Could you try to get a backtrace when it runs out of memory? It could be lots of things, including any custom hooks you might have implemented.

Comment: I will try to get one. I can't replicate the memory issue but keep getting reports, so I have asked them to note the exact date and time and a few other things to help me track further info about the error.

Answer (score 2):

What is the default dedupe rules you are using? is this the standard ones or did you customise?

In general, the performance problems I experienced on civi the same size as yours are

1) badly configured server (eg mysql with wrong variables...). I would recommend you to run mysqltuner, you need to read the doc before blindly following their advices, but it's mostly good
2) modified dedupe rules (this one is a performance killer)
3) smartgroups (easy to kill your server with that one too)

It's probably worthwhile to check the load of your server and mysql configuration in any case, but dedupe rules are usually close next indeed

Comment: Thank you, I will look into these. I believe the dedupe rule for orgs is default/unchanged.